# writing 8-bit png with a transparent color from C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, png, transparency, png-8

I've got some code to generate false-color synthetic images from side scan sonar data that I want to load into Google Earth as overlays.  I need to be space efficient, so 8-bit PNG files seemed to be the way to go.  I can use 1 color table entry for background and 255 for my false color table.

I saw previous answers that recommended the CImage class in the ATL library. So I look up the MSDN documentation here (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5eb252d0(v=vs.100).aspx)

It looks straight forward enough so I coded something like this:

```
CImage Cimg;
Cimg.Create(width,height,8,0);

RGBQUAD ColorTable[256];
for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    // Fill table.
Cimg.SetTransparentColor(long(255));
Cimg.SetColorTable(0,256,Ctable);

// fill the pixel values.

Cimg.Save("TestFile.png",Gdiplus::ImageFormatPNG);
```

Everything works more or less as expected, but color 255 is just another color.  It's not transparent at all.

I know this is not an issue with GoogleEarth, because I can load the file into Paint Shop Pro and manually set the background clear, and then everything works great.

I've tried setting the .rgbReserved byte in the RGBQUAD table to all zeros, 255s and a ramp, thinking it may be interpreted as the Alpha value, but that had no effect.

I also tried stepping through the implementation of CImage::Save() where I determined it's using Gdiplus::Bitmap::Save() to do the write with the "Built In PNG Encoder".  I thought maybe there were some encoder parameters which weren't getting set right, but this MSDN page suggests there are zero parameters for the PNG encoder.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms533846(v=vs.85).aspx

So, um, I guess my question is "HELP!"   :-)

More specifically, does anyone know if any of the MSDN native functions will let me generate 8-bit PNGs with a palate I can define and at least one transparent color?  A simple fix would be great, but I'm annoyed enough with CImage now that I'm willing to abandon it and try something else.

Alternatively, does anyone know if there is a command line utility that could be used to fix the broken background color?

Thanks!

Comment: `SetTransparentColor(int color);`  Will turn color 255 to the transparent color (i.e. if your mask is ARGB then blue becomes transparent).  Are you setting that correctly?  Also .png *should* have alpha data and setting this seems redundant.   Are you sure of your input format and the color you want the alpha channel to be (if it does not have alpha already).

Comment: There is no input format.  I'm generating the image programmatically.  

I used comments to represent the filling of the 256 RGB values, and the filling of the data array in the image with bytes. But I've checked in the debugger and that's working right...

I tried calling Cimg.SetTransparentColor(255) both before and after the call to Cimg.SetColorTable(), and they are both called before the Cimg.Save() call is made.

I agree that SetTransparentColor(255) *SHOULD* turn color 255 transparent, but it's NOT happening.  If you have seen this work, please give an example I can code up and try!

Comment: From my understanding of the MSDN docs, 32 bit PNG can have a full alpha channel, but 8-bit PNG images can just have 1 code be clear. (though it doesn't seem to work and the documentation is incredibly circular)

Comment: By reading the PNG file format here: http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Structure.html
and looking at the "chunk" data in a broken file written by MSDN and the same file rewritten by Paint Shop Pro after the broken transparency is repaired (I inspected the files with a hex editor)I've learned a few things.

1st: PNG allows for an optional 8-bit alpha value for *every* entry in the color palette.  It doesn't have to be just one and the transparency doesn't have to be binary.

2nd: MSDN completely fails to write the optional data chunk, which should be named 'tRNS'.

Comment: For now I've written an embarrassingly brittle routine to hack the files after MSDN writes them, to add the missing 'tRNS chunk'.  For now, it's got me unstuck, but I fear the flames of hell will come find me, if I leave that hack in the code...

There must be a legitimate way to do this.  PNG files with a completely general 256 entry RGBA palette seems like way to good a thing not to support!

Comment: "MSDN" is Microsoft Developer Network; it's not software but documentation. I've got no idea which software you're describing.

Comment: C++ under Visual Studio 2010.  I made clear which routine I'm using in the first link of my first post.  Did you bother reading it before replying? Your reputation is 62000, but so far I'm not impressed.  I hope you haven't spent all of that time just snarking on other people's typos...

Comment: If you are concerned about file size, then it's helpful to use index 0 for the transparent color instead of 255; that way the PNG file can contain a one-entry (3 byte) tRNS chunk instead of a 256-entry (768 bytes) one.